# Update sharepoint file property using Sharepoint API

Tags: api, sharepoint

Trying to update the file Title property by using Sharepoint API.
I wrote the following code:

```
public static void updateFile(String relativeUri){
        HttpRequest reqWrite = new HttpRequest();
    Http httpWrite = new Http();
    relativeUri = '/MyLibrary/MyFolder/MyFile.docx';
    String endpoint = 'https://mysharepointsite.com/sites/organization/_api/web/getFileByServerRelativeUrl(\''+relativeUri+'\')/ListItemAllFields';
    reqWrite.setEndpoint(endpoint);
    reqWrite.setMethod('PUT');

    String body = '{ \'__metadata\': { \'type\': \'SP.ListItem\' }, \'ServerRelativeUrl\': \''+relativeUri+'\'}, \'Title\':\'MyCustomTitle\'}';
    System.debug(body);
    reqWrite.setBody(body);
    reqWrite.setHeader('Accept', SharePointOnlineWebserviceCallout_Helper.JSON_CONTENT_TYPE);
    reqWrite.setHeader('Content-Type', SharePointOnlineWebserviceCallout_Helper.JSON_CONTENT_TYPE);
    if(SharePointOnlineWebserviceCallout_Helper.ACCESS_TOKEN ==null){
        SharePointOnlineWebserviceCallout_Helper.ACCESS_TOKEN  = getAccessToken();
    }
    String accessToken = SharePointOnlineWebserviceCallout_Helper.ACCESS_TOKEN ;
    reqWrite.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer '+ accessToken);
    System.debug(LoggingLevel.Finest, 'ENDPOINT:' +endpoint);
   // System.debug(LoggingLevel.Finest, 'BODY:' +body);
     HttpResponse resWrite = new HttpResponse();       
      System.debug('REQWRITE: '+reqWrite);
    try{ 
        resWrite = httpWrite.send(reqWrite);
        System.debug('resWrite-->'+resWrite);

    }         
    catch(Exception e){
        System.debug('Callout error: '+ e.getMessage());
    }           
    }
```

But the response says 'BAD Request', did I miss something here? Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried making a request using curl or postman?

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is invalid. Here's what comes out of a linter:

```
{
    '__metadata': {
        'type': 'SP.ListItem'
    },
    'ServerRelativeUrl': ''
}, 'Title': 'MyCustomTitle'
}
```

The braces are unbalanced, and you should be using double quotes rather than single quotes.